# Squashed images horizontally on iPhone devices only

Tags: css, responsive-design

Images are being squashed horizontally on physical iPhone devices.

I cannot replicate the issue in dev tools / browser mobile emulation at all (any phones). The images look absolutely fine on my mobile (Samsung Galaxy A51).

Example below:

[image: Images squashed in iPhone devices]

The only styles on these images are:

```
padding: 10px 0;
margin: 0 auto;

max-width: 95%;
max-height: initial !important;

display: block;
```

Comment: Are you using `display: flex;` on a container somewhere? IOS seems to screw that up sometimes

Comment: Yes. I was wondering if it might be something to do with flex myself. This style applies to it's immediate container: `flex: 0 0 100%;`.

Comment: Thanks @NicoShultzfor pointing me in right direction. I have applied `align-self: center;` to the images and it has fixed the issue.